# Highlight/Show Objects Paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

When I select an object its path gets highlighted in its respective color, and this made me wonder, if it is possible to highlight/show all objects paths in some way without them being selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to switch to `Outline mode` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>